# How to show once an UIVIewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I’m making an app, and I need to show only one time the on boarding view controller, so when the user re enter the app the on boarding view controller doesn’t appear any more.

Comment: Use storage which keeps data permanently(at least while app is installed). Such as `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the on boarding view controller is your initial view controller. Try this in app delegate

First put `checkFunction()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then set the identity (eg. `Home`) for the view controller you want to go

```
func checkFunction() {
    let acceptedTerms = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "acceptedTerms")
    if acceptedTerms != nil && acceptedTerms == "Yes" {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let VC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
        self.window?.rootViewController = VC
    }
}
```

Second, modify `UserDefaults.standard.string` in somewhere

```
// example
@IBAction func acceptButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "acceptedTerms")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: The use of `synchronize` is obsolete.